# C++ compilation error: ‘pair’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to compile very simple c++ program by g++ compiler.

```
//main.cpp 

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> pii;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting compilation error: ‘pair’ does not name a type

Compile line: g++ main.cpp -o main.out
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 lts
g++: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)

If I just add `#include<iostrem>` program compiles and runs successfully:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> pii;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Do you know, why is this happens?

Comment: You know what headers are for, do you?

Comment: Because, 1. You need to include the right header file, and 2. you need to completely [forget that `using namespace std;` exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Any C++ standard header is allowed to include any other header, so a random header might do it. The best way is to include the `<utility>` header where [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is supposed to be declared.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My fault, answer is easy:)

1) For using `pair` I should include `<utility>`.

2) `<iostream>` somewhere includes `<utility>`, that's why after adding it program compiles successfully:)